# How can I convert the given array of objects into the required one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I need to convert the array of objects into the given one. I am stuck on this for the past week. Can't find a simple method to do it

I have tried using map-reduce but in the end, it confused me. If anyone could help me with this just by for loop, it'll be helpful.
I created an empty array and then after sorting the input via stepId, I am unable to proceed.

```
[
    {
        "stepType": "FS",
        "title": "New Form Page",
        "stepId": "step1",
        "sectionTitle": "title",
        "Type": "text",
        "Id": "Id",
        "Title": "Id"
    },
    {
        "stepType": "FS",
        "title": "New Form Page",
        "stepId": "step1",
        "sectionTitle": "title",
        "Type": "number",
        "Id": "Id",
        "Title": "Id"
    },
    {
        "stepType": "FS",
        "title": "New Form Page",
        "stepId": "step1",
        "sectionTitle": "title",
        "Type": "mobile",
        "Id": "Id",
        "Title": "Id"
    },
    {
        "stepType": "FS",
        "title": "New Form Page",
        "stepId": "step2",
        "sectionTitle": "title",
        "Type": "date",
        "Id": "New element",
        "Title": "New element"
    } ]
```

Expected output

```
[
    {
      "stepType": "FS",
      "title": "New Form Page",
      "id": "step1",
      "sections": [
        {
          "title": "title",
          "elements": [
            {
              "type": "text",
              "id": "Id",
              "title": "Id"
            },
            {
              "type": "number",
              "id": "Id",
              "title": "Id"
            },
            {
              "type": "mobile",
              "id": "Id",
              "title": "Id"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "stepType": "FS",
      "title": "New form Page",
      "id": "step2",
      "sections": [
        {
          "title": "title",
          "elements": [
            {
              "type": "date",
              "id": "",
              "title": "New element"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Comment: What you have tried, please share your code.

Comment: can you at least add an end expected output..

Comment: @StefanAvramovic added the expected output

Comment: The expected output is the second array. Maybe add a comment between the input and output to make the question more clear?

Comment: @BeaST30 - I rolledback to your edit where names are anonymized. I don't suggest changing JSON properties of the model in your question, as all answers have been answered using that original JSON data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to do that.

We iterate over given array, and

1. If we find an array element with matching `stepId`

   - And a `section` with matching `sectionTitle`, then we push current item into that section's `elements` array.
   - If we don't find a matching `section` with `sectionTitle`, then we create a new `section` with current item's values.
2. If we don't find an array element with matching `stepId`, then we create a new element with current item's values.

```js
var data = [ { "stepType": "formStep", "title": "New Form Page", "stepId": "step1", "sectionTitle": "title", "Type": "text", "Id": "Pranjal", "Title": "Pranjal" }, { "stepType": "formStep", "title": "New Form Page", "stepId": "step1", "sectionTitle": "title", "Type": "number", "Id": "Shubham", "Title": "Shubham" }, { "stepType": "formStep", "title": "New Form Page", "stepId": "step1", "sectionTitle": "title", "Type": "mobile", "Id": "Varun", "Title": "Varun" }, { "stepType": "formStep", "title": "New Form Page", "stepId": "step2", "sectionTitle": "title", "Type": "date", "Id": "New element", "Title": "New element" } ];

let result = data.reduce((arr, currentValue) => {

      let item = arr.find(item => item.id === currentValue.stepId);

      if (item) {
        let section = item.sections.find(
          section => section.title === currentValue.sectionTitle);
        if (section) {
          section.elements.push({
            "type": currentValue.Type,
            "id": currentValue.Id,
            "title": currentValue.Title
          });
        } else {
          item.sections.push({
              "title": currentValue.sectionTitle,
              "elements": [{
                "type": currentValue.Type,
                "id": currentValue.Id,
                "title": currentValue.Title
              }]
            });
          }
        } else {
          arr.push({
            "stepType": currentValue.stepType,
            "title": currentValue.title,
            "id": currentValue.stepId,
            "sections": [{
              "title": currentValue.sectionTitle,
              "elements": [{
                "type": currentValue.Type,
                "id": currentValue.Id,
                "title": currentValue.Title
              }]
            }]
          });
        }

        return arr;
      }, []);

    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`convertData();` will loop through the objects in the array. for each object it will inspect the property names and determine how it should look in the final result.

```js
var data = [{"stepType":"formStep","title":"New Form Page","stepId":"step1","sectionTitle":"title","Type":"text","Id":"Pranjal","Title":"Pranjal"},{"stepType":"formStep","title":"New Form Page","stepId":"step1","sectionTitle":"title","Type":"number","Id":"Shubham","Title":"Shubham"},{"stepType":"formStep","title":"New Form Page","stepId":"step1","sectionTitle":"title","Type":"mobile","Id":"Varun","Title":"Varun"},{"stepType":"formStep","title":"New Form Page","stepId":"step2","sectionTitle":"title","Type":"date","Id":"New element","Title":"New element"}];
        
function convertData() {
 var arr = [];
 for(var d = 0; d < data.length; d++) {
  var item = data[d];
  var obj = {};
  var sections = [];
  var section = { elements: {} };
  for(var key in item) {
   let newKey = key.toLowerCase();
   if (key==='stepId') {
    obj.id = item[key];
   }
   if (key==='sectionTitle') {
    section.title = item[key];
   } else if (key==='Type' || key==='Id' || key==='Title') {
    section.elements[newKey] = item[key];
   }
  }
  sections.push(section);
  obj.sections = section;
  arr.push(obj);
 }
 console.log(arr);
}

convertData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that would do that. It is not very beautiful, but it does do the job:

```js
const data = [
{
    "stephome": "FS",
    "title": "TITLE",
    "score": "step1",
    "game": "title",
    "home": "mobile"
},
{
    "stephome": "FS",
    "title": "TITLE",
    "score": "step2",
    "game": "title",
    "home": "date"
} ]

function makeData(steps) {
    let tempArr = [];

    // Run through all steps
    steps.forEach(step => {
        let innerStep;
        let section;
        // If the step with that Id exists, get it and modify it 
        let existingStep = tempArr.filter(temp => temp.id == step.score);
        if(existingStep.length > 0) {
            innerStep = existingStep[0];

            // Same for the sections
            let existingSection = innerStep.sections
                .filter(stepSections => stepSections.title == step.sectionTitle);
            if(existingSection.length > 0) {
                section = existingSection[0];
            }
        // If the step does not exist, create a new one and add it to the output
        } else {
            innerStep = {
                stephome: step.stephome,
                title: step.title,
                id: step.score,
                sections: []
            };
            tempArr.push(innerStep);
        }

        // If the section does not exist, create a new one and add it to the step
        if(section == undefined) {
            section = {
                title: step.sectionTitle,
                elements: []
            }
            innerStep.sections.push(section);
        }

        // Add the element to the sections array
        section.elements.push({
            home: step.home
        });
    });
    return tempArr;
}

console.log(makeData(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the wanted nesting by taking an array of key for gouping and other keys for the actual level, as well as the key the the nested array.

Then you could take an object for the alias of the keys in the new objects.

This works for an arbitrary count of nesting levels for grouping.

```js
var data = [{ stepType: "formStep", title: "New Form Page", stepId: "step1", sectionTitle: "title", Type: "text", Id: "Pranjal", Title: "Pranjal" }, { stepType: "formStep", title: "New Form Page", stepId: "step1", sectionTitle: "title", Type: "number", Id: "Shubham", Title: "Shubham" }, { stepType: "formStep", title: "New Form Page", stepId: "step1", sectionTitle: "title", Type: "mobile", Id: "Varun", Title: "Varun" }, { stepType: "formStep", title: "New Form Page", stepId: "step2", sectionTitle: "title", Type: "date", Id: "New element", Title: "New element" }],
    alias = {
        stepId: 'id',
        sectionTitle: 'title',
        Type: 'type',
        ID: 'id',
        Title: 'title'
    },
    groups = [
        ['stepId', 'stepType', 'title', 'sections'],
        ['sectionTitle', 'elements'],
        [undefined, 'Type', 'Id', 'Title', undefined]
    ],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        groups.reduce((p, [group, ...properties]) => {
            function setProperties(target = {}) {
                properties.forEach(k => target[alias[k] || k] = o[k]);
                return target;
            }

            var collection = properties.pop(),
                temp;

            if (!group) {
                p.push(setProperties());
                return [];
            }

            temp = p.find(q => o[group] === q[alias[group] || group]);
            if (!temp) {
                p.push(temp = setProperties({ [alias[group] || group]: o[group] }));
                temp[collection] = [];
            }

            return temp[collection];
        }, r)
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @NinaScholz would you mind letting me know how you created the "run code as snippet"? I'm have trouble finding the info on how to do that in answers. Ty

Comment: @daddygames, just press the 7th button in the answer with `<>` sign in a sheet.

Comment: @NinaScholz I appreciate your help! Ty!